# QFile/QDir: force move mode only?

Tags: qt

`QFile`/`QDir` `rename` function copies file in the case it's not possible to just move it.

Is there a  way to learn in advance what type of operation will occur?

Let's suppose I have `10 GB` file. In case of copy, I would definitely like to use my own copy function and show UI with the progress of the operation.

And of course I do not want to use my copy function always if the fast move is available.

Comment: A quick glance at Qt sources suggests, there is no way in the official API. So I see two ways forward for you: 1. write platform-specific code yourself. 2. Make Qt do the move/copy in different thread, so GUI thread won't be blocked, and you can use for example QProgressDialog easily if the other thread takes too long (more than a few hundred milliseconds maybe).

Comment: Link for reference and as starting point if you want to browse how Qt does it (note how there are different file system engine implementations for Unix and Win under the hood): https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfile.cpp.html#_ZN5QFile6renameERK7QString (and `d->engine()->rename(newName)` is where that function calls the underlying engine).